# Retrieving character's flanking region

Tags: python, dna-sequence

I'm trying to localize a particular character "r" in a line and then retrieve the 35characters flanking it on each side. There could be more than one "r" so I'm trying to obtain all of them. I've been trying this code but I'm only getting the headers and I cant figure it out. Any advice?

```
fhand=open("input.txt")
target = open ("output.txt", "a")
for line in fhand:
    name, id, seq= line.split("\t")
    while atpos < len(seq):
        if atpos == -1:
            break
        atpos = seq.find ("r")
        seq2 = seq[(atpos-35):(atpos+36)]
        line2= name + "\t"+ id + "\t" + seq2 + "\n"
        target.write(line2)
        atpos += 1

print ("Sequences obtained successfully")
target.close()
```

Comment: I think you want `line2= name + "\t"+ id + "\t" + seq2 + "\n"`

Comment: ya sorry for that but still gives me an endless list of headers..

Comment: `atpos` is not defined at its first use. The code you've posted should give you a `NameError`. Please show us the actual code you're using, as well as a sample `input.txt`

Comment: That was the actual code, I think it just goes into an eternal loop, the script keeps working without an error..  It already worked using the code below but still would be great to know whats wrong with this one..

Comment: `while atpos < len(seq)` <- `atpos` is not defined when this loop is executed for the first time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import csv

with open("input.txt") as infile, open('output.txt', 'w') as fout:
    outfile = csv.writer(fout, delimiter='\t')
    for name, id, seq in csv.reader(infile, delimiter='\t'):
        locs = [i for i,char in enumerate(seq) if char=='r']
        for loc in locs:
            outfile.writerow([name, id, seq[max(loc-35, 0) : loc+36]])
```

Comment: good answer, but here is not [code review SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: It didnt work for me man. It gave me a syntax error. Python 3?

Comment: @Ale: I won't be able to help out without an error message

Comment: File "<stdin>", line 6
    outfile.writerow([name, id, seq[max(loc-35, 0) : loc+36])
     SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Yeah, the edit worked! genius!  The only problem is that I'm not familiar with the code but I'll look into the use of locs. Thanks man